# Get text and text color from font class

Tags: javascript

It could be silly question, but I just can't find any working example for this problem.

On site I got something like this:

```
<li>
<font class="profile_font" name="profile_font_status">Status:</font> 
<font class="profile_font" name="profile_font_online" color="green"><b>ONLINE</b></font>
```

How could I get text "ONLINE" into variable using JavaScript and how could I get color into variable?

Comment: Search for `querySelector()`, attribute-value selector and `textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var el = document.querySelector("font[name=profile_font_online]");
var online = el.textContent;
var color = el.getAttribute("color");
```

**Explanation:**

- Use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find the element by querying for the name
- Use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to retrieve the text
- Use the [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) function to retrieve the contents of the colour attribute

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using javascript only for color. use  tag

```
<li>
<font class="profile_font" name="profile_font_status">Status:</font> 
<font class="profile_font" name="profile_font_online"><b><span style="color:green;">ONLINE</span></b></font>
</li>
```

OR

```
<li>
<font class="profile_font" name="profile_font_status">Status:</font> 
<font class="profile_font" name="profile_font_online" style="color:green;"><b>ONLINE</b></font>
</li>
```

Comment: It's not my site. I just try to run script to check if status is online.

Comment: When posting a code example please make sure that the syntax is correct.